# Getmetadata function not showing fieldlist as structure

Tags: azure-data-factory

I wanted to validate a schema of parquet file using getmetadata .however I'm unable to get structure as option in field list to compare schema, So I tried for .CSV file dint get structure option for CSV as wel.under what circumstance does it show structure as field list??

How do I validate schema and column count using ADF without data flow??

Answer (score 1):

Please provide the screenshot of your dataset properties?

Basically if your datatset path is mapped to a folder , you wont get the structure option but in case if it is file, then you would get it.
As structure is a property of file

Also :
[image]

Similar thread :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1338303/how-to-get-structure-from-field-list-in-azure-data